Can standard deviations from multiple studies be averaged to use for a sample size calculation?
Imagine you are planning a clinical trial to evaluate the effectiveness of a new treatment for improving VO2peak in patients with chronic stroke. Based on an initial study by Jin et al., you estimate the sample size needed for the trial using the variance in VO2peak reported by Jin et al.
Data from Jin et al.:

Standard Deviation (SD) in VO2peak: 2.5 ml/kg/min
Estimated Sample Size: 40 participants per group

However, you later observe that the SD in your pilot study is much higher than Jin et al.’s estimate.
Data from Other Studies:

DaCun: SD = 10 ml/kg/min
Mac: SD = 15 ml/kg/min
Len: SD = 20 ml/kg/min
Ive: SD = 18 ml/kg/min
Glob: SD = 25 ml/kg/min

Revised Approach:
Instead of relying solely on Jin et al.’s SD estimate, you now include data from these additional studies:

Average SD from Other Studies: (10 + 15 + 20 + 18 + 25) / 5 = 17.6 ml/kg/min

Revised Sample Size Calculation: Using this higher average SD, you calculate a new sample size estimate.


Outcome:

New Sample Size Estimate: 80 participants per group (based on the higher average SD)

IS THIS AN ACCEPTABLE APPROACH TO CALCULATE SAMPLE SIZE?

Welcome to Cross Validated! Are those values variances or standard deviations (SDs)? The units (ml/kg/min, the same as VO2peak) suggest that they are SDs. Do you know the number of subjects in all these studies? What you need is a weighted average of variances, not SDs. Please edit the question to address those matters. Also, the way this is presented suggests that it might be a homework or self-study exercise rather than a project you are designing. If so, please look at the guidance about "Homework" on this help page.

Thanks EdM! Yes, these are SDs, and I have edited the question now.

You need to use formulae for the pooled variance of subgroups
Obtaining a pooled variance from multiple subgroups is a bit more complicated than what you are proposing here (see related question here).  You can find relevant formulae for this (and for higher-order moments) in O'Neill (2021).  If you have a look at the formulae in these resources you will see that it is possible to pool the variance of a set of subgroups so long as you know the sample size, mean and variance of each subgroup.  This computation is automated in the sample.decomp function in the utilities package.  This function can compute pooled sample moments from subgroup moments, or compute missing subgroup moments from the other subgroup moments and pooled moments.  It works for decompositions up to fourth order ---i.e., decompositions of sample size, sample mean, sample variance/standard deviation, sample skewness, and sample kurtosis.
In the code below I give an example of how you could compute this in R.  This example uses made up values for the sample sizes and sample means of your groups, so you should supplant these with the actual values from the studies.

#Create some subgroups of mock data and a pooled dataset
NAMES <- c('Jin et al', 'Da Cun', 'Mac', 'Len', 'Ive', 'Glob')
N     <- c(40, 52, 60, 15, 22, 35)
MEANS <- c(21.1, 22.6, 18.2, 13.4, 24.0, 24.2)
VARS  <- c(2.5^2, 10^2, 15^2, 20^2, 18^2, 25^2)
DATA  <- data.frame(n = N, sample.mean = MEANS, sample.var = VARS)
rownames(DATA) <- NAMES

#Show sample statistics for the subgroups
library(utilities)
sample.decomp(n = N, sample.mean = MEANS, sample.var  = VARS, names = rownames(DATA))

             n sample.mean sample.var
Jin et al   40      21.100     6.2500
Da Cun      52      22.600   100.0000
Mac         60      18.200   225.0000
Len         15      13.400   400.0000
Ive         22      24.000   324.0000
Glob        35      24.200   625.0000
--pooled-- 224      20.925   243.4897



This may seem like a simple question at first, but it is actually more involved than it first appears.
Short answer; yes, that is an acceptable approach. But simple averaging may be a coarse approximation, as further detailed below (if the sample sizes are quite different, if the observed means are quite different, etc.). However, for estimating a sample size (which anyway has many other assumptions), small deviations from mathematical truth may only be marginally relevant, thus this approach may serve.
Caveat; it is the variances you need to average, not the sd's. But the values you quote, based on the units, look like standard deviations. And for computing sample size, usually one feeds standard deviations into the software. To get the average sd, you average the variances (square of the sd's), and take the square root of that average. For $k$ studies, with respective standard deviations $sd_i$,
$$sd_{\text{average}}=\sqrt {\frac {(sd_1)^2+(sd_2)^2+\cdots+(sd_k)^2} {k}}.$$
Note that what we are doing here, is not really "averaging" the studies, but mixing all the samples, to create a much larger sample, and trying to estimate the standard deviation of this mixture (the proper technical term). You are aggregating all these samples, as if they are one bigger sample. This of course assumes that all of these are samples from the same exact population, taken under the same conditions, etc. (and if that is not true, one has no business averaging or mixing anything between these studies)
Longer answer; the above answer glosses over several "details" (and we know who hides in the details). First, it ignores that we are dealing with sample variances (not population variances; yes, this pesky Bessel correction), and second it assumes that the sample sizes in all the studies are the same (or pretty close), which most likely they are not. So we probably should take a weighted average of the variances, to account for the possibly of different samples sizes in the various studies. Now, given the end purpose (finding a sample size) this may be overkill. But on the other hand, the math is not that hard. So, why not try that... For $k$ studies, with respective standard deviations $sd_i$ and sample sizes $n_i$,
$$sd_{\text{mixture}}=\sqrt {\frac {(n_1-1)(sd_1)^2+(n_2-1)(sd_2)^2+\cdots+(n_k-1)(sd_k)^2} {n_1+n_2+\cdots +n_k-1}}.$$
Even longer answer; this was all good, but the above ignored the differences in means between the various studies. So, for $k$ studies, with respective standard deviations $sd_i$, means $\bar x_i$ and sample sizes $n_i$,the above formula becomes
$$sd_{\text{mixture}}=\sqrt {\frac {(n_1-1)(sd_1)^2+(n_2-1)(sd_2)^2+\cdots+(n_k-1)(sd_k)^2} {n_1+n_2+\cdots+ n_k-1} +
 \frac{n_1(\bar x_1 -\bar x)^2+n_2(\bar x_2-\bar x)^2+\cdots+ n_k(\bar x_k-\bar x)^2}{n_1+n_2+\cdots+ n_k-1}}$$,
where $\bar x$ is the grand mean of the mixture, which is the weighted average of the means of the various studies
$\bar x= \frac {n_1 \bar x_1 + n_2 \bar x_2 +\cdots+n_k \bar x_k} {n_1+n_2+\cdots+n_k}.$
Last, you may also want to read the following post on CV; it has more detailed derivations of the formulas, and the reasons for it. Be sure to read carefully, as not all answer are relevant, and some comments have excellent answers.
